# Check if match 3 or more match in DB row

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I need help to find out, how I can check if 3 or more columns already exists in a row and get a true/false result.

Example of my Table:

```
ID | NAME | REF | DOORS | ITEMS
1 | MASTER | 4 | 3 | 2
2 | MASTER | 2 | 3 | 4
```

Example 1:

```
strName = "MASTER"
strRef 4
strDoors = 3
strItems = 1
```

See my strings above, here you can see
`NAME,REF,DOORS` is the same values in a row in my `database(3 match)`, so this should return af `TRUE result`.

Example 2:

```
strName = "MASTER"
strRef 1
strDoors = 1
strItems = 1
```

In this Example, is it `ONLY NAME` what is the same in a row, but the others are different, and it should return af `FALSE result`.

Can anybody give me a idea to a SQL string or script, to how i can resolve this?
Hope it's make any sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I think these sql will helpful to you. Please check it.

**Example 1** SQL returns TRUE.

```
  Example 1:- SELECT CASE WHEN  NAME = "MASTER" AND Ref = 4 
               AND strDoors = 3 AND  Items = 1 THEN 'TRUE ' 
               ELSE 'FALSE' END FROM mytable
```

**Example 2** SQL returns FALSE.

```
Example 2:- SELECT CASE WHEN  NAME = "MASTER" AND Ref = 1 
            AND strDoors = 1 AND  Items = 1 THEN 'TRUE ' 
            ELSE 'FALSE' END FROM mytable
```

Thank You.